# Shopify - Editing some code to display Recommended Products in BLOG post

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

Cheers to anyone that can help! ♡

http://pastebin.com/HRrtd3gA - This small snippet shows related products, if you’re on a **product page** with the include `{% include 'related-products' %}` on the *products.liquid* page.

However, if I include that on the *article.liquid* page, it returns no results. This is because the snippet checks to see what the current product is being viewed, and then gets related products from related collections.

So my question is:-

What do I edit in the related-products snippet, so it outputs literally **anything** from **any** collection, on a page that has the include (my blog/article page), which **doesn't** have a product to pull related products from? From my basic understanding it has to do with around line 42?

Thanks to anyone who can help! Much appreciated.

Comment: It's better to create a new functionality because there is a huge difference between "recommended" and "related" and you can't reuse the snippet. Just create a Recommended collection and output the products in the blog post directly.

Comment: You should assign a product in the blog page to get access to it's metafields.